# Efficient way of getting thread CPU time using JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I'm currently getting the total thread CPU time using JMX in the following manner:

```
private long calculateTotalThreadCpuTime(ThreadMXBean thread) {

    long totalTime = 0l;

    for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : thread.dumpAllThreads(false, false))
        totalTime += thread.getThreadCpuTime(threadInfo.getThreadId());

    return totalTime;
}
```

As the ThreadMXBean is actually a remote proxy, performance is *dreadful*, in the order of magnitude of seconds for this actual method call.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

---

**Update**: I'm using this for performance monitoring. The measurements were both 'wall clock' time and JProfiler, which showed about 85% of my time spent in this method. I do have some other MXBean calls ( Runtime, Memory, GC ), but they are much cheaper. Most likely because every call to `thread.getThreadCpuTime` is a remote one.

**Update 2**: JProfiler screenshot showing the performance problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimisations:

- invoke getThreadCPUTime inside a thread pool, since it seems to be network-bound;
- whenever a thread is found to be in `Thread.STATE.TERMINATED`, keep its name in a Map and skip querying the next time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use non-standard APIs, you can cast `OperatingSystemMXBean` to `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` and invoke `getProcessCpuTime()`, as described in [Using a Sun internal class to get JVM CPU time](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking#UsingaSuninternalclasstogetJVMCPUtime) on David Robert Nadeau's blog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not ideal, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

It must be the remote nature of your calls that is the problem.

I recently did a spike on asking a thread for CPU time uses and it was incredibly faster.  In the context of a web application request it was nearly immeasurable.  If one went into a hard loop it would costs you but typically you want it at the start of an operation and again at the end.

Comment: Right, in the same JVM it should be cheap but I'm doing it over RMI.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the poor performance is that each call of `thread.getThreadCpuTime()` will (in your case of a remote proxy) most probably result in an RMI/Remote JMX call which of course is expensive, especially when the message is actually sent via TCP (and maybe even outside localhost).
[*(see JMX 1.4 spec, chapter 7.3)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/JMX_1_4_specification.pdf)

Although JMX defines [multiple attribute retrieval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIConnection.html#getAttributes%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20javax.security.auth.Subject%29) at once this will not help you out here
because `thread.getThreadCpuTime(long)` is not an JMX attribute but a remote method invocation (and additionally, the ThreadInfo object on which the methods is invoked differs by each call)

Unfortunately, the JMX 1.4 spec does not define something like *"invoke multiple methods of multiple objects and return their return values at all"*.
So beside concurrent invocation (which will save time but will not reduce the effort) of these calls I am not aware of any (compatible) optimizations here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you talk more about how you're planning on using this information?  You can get thread CPU times using a JVMTI based agent, which should perform slightly better than JMX.  How have you measured the overhead of the JMX approach that lead you to the conclusion of 'dreadful' performance?

Comment: I'm using this for performance monitoring. The measurements were both 'wall clock' time and JProfiler, which showed about 85% of my time spent in this method. I do have some other MXBean calls ( Runtime, Memory, GC ), but they are much cheaper.